# Follow up to "Whats the best way to arrange latex documents"

Tags: document-configuration

A follow up question
[What's the best way to arrange LaTeX documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47944/whats-the-best-way-to-arrange-latex-documents)

There are couples of characteristics to my data described in original question –

1. Verse numbers are unique
2. Authors name is unique
3. For commentaries I created a unique identification number with a prefix c1, c2 etc to verse numbers.

This is how I arranged the documents, I used “Concatenate” in excel to create individual tex file structure shown below

Verses

```
\section{here verse 1 } \label{v1.1.1}
\section{here verse 2} \label{v1.1.2}   etc etc …. For all verses
```

All commentaries by Author_Name_A

```
\paragraph{Here commentary 1 by Author A for verse 1 } \label{c1.1.1.1}
\paragraph{Here commentary 1 by Author A for verse 2 } \label{c1.1.1.2} etc etc ….
```

All commentaries by Author_Name_B

```
\paragraph{Here commentary 2 by Author B for verse 1 } \label{c2.1.1.1}
\paragraph{Here commentary 2 by Author B for verse 2 } \label{c2.1.1.2} etc etc ….
```

All commentaries by Author_Name_C

```
\paragraph{Here commentary 3 by Author C for verse 1 } \label{c31.1.1}
\paragraph{Here commentary 3 by Author C for verse 2 } \label{c31.1.2} etc etc ….
```

I ran these files separately in different directory – I got Aux files for each of the above TeX files. Which I copied into my working directory and created new TeX file called “All_Commentaries.TeX” which looks as below

```
\nameref{v1.1.1}
\nameref{c1.1.1.1}
\nameref{c2.1.1.1}
\nameref{c3.1.1.1}

\newpage 

\nameref{v1.1.2}
\nameref{c1.1.1.2}
\nameref{c2.1.1.2}
\nameref{c3.1.1.2}
```

This is how my main file looks like which produces desired output as shown in the attached image to original question.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\RequirePackage{mypackage}

\includeonly{ All_Commentaries}

\begin{document}

\inclue{ All_Commentaries }
\include{Verse}
\include{ Author_Name_A}
\include{ Author_Name_B}
\include{ Author_Name_C}

\end{document}
```

Now my question are -

Is this approach scalable ?
Are there any flaws in this approach, is there a better and efficient approach for this. 
Many times I get this error `Package hyperref Warning: The anchor of a bookmark and its parent's must not
(hyperref)                be the same. Added a new anchor on input line 41.`
 
Your comments and suggestions to improve my work would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the "data" (verses and commentaries) already in excel?

Comment: Yes I do have all the data in Excel. Its all unicode characters as well (Sanskrit)

Comment: Is there a reason for having all the commentaries in Excel, or in an external file at all?

Comment: No there is no reason, I had to write `\section{here verse 1 } \label{v1.1.1}` in this way for latex I did not want to type 1000 times `section{` & `\label{v1.1.1}` so I copied everything to excel, used concatenate feature and copied back to tex file just to save repeated typing. In the entire process described above - excel is used to save repeated typing thats all.