# How to produce layers of running commentaries?

Tags: xetex, memoir, ledmac

I am looking to make a quite common document for which I'm nevertheless having difficulty finding the right package/setup.  I want to produce a Sanskrit document (using xelatex) of a base text with several commentaries.  The look of it would be similar to what you find in the image [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47944/whats-the-best-way-to-arrange-latex-documents), except that there isn't an initial section for vocabulary. The tricky thing is that each commentary needs to be linked to the base text (similar to footnotes in ledmac) but they can be very long, stretching several pages for just a single verse in the base text, and they will have lots of other formatting: e.g., paragraph breaks, verse citations, etc.  I've been trying to tweak ledmac (using memoir) but so far with not much luck.  It's important, as in ledmac, that the commentaries all remain in the same position on each page (commentary 1 coming just below the base text; commentary 2 below that, etc.). Is there some simple solution I'm missing (as I suspect)?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood right, you wanted to have this features in ledmac ? https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/52

I hope to add this feature when the ledmac 1.0 will be out. (But I asked for test in new version).

Comment: That is exactly the functionality I was looking for!  Thank you for the tip.  I'll check back to see when that feature is added.  I'd be happy to test it out in the runup to the new release of ledmac.  I'll leave this question open for the moment because I'm curious how people are producing these texts now

Comment: If you want to make more fast the features add, you can test new beta 1 of ledmac 1.0 https://lists.berlios.de/pipermail/ledmac-users/2012-September/000061.html

Comment: for the next of conversation, please answer to the featur, to say you are interessted too : I will answer in this place